# Java - get top 15 from HashMap by rule

Tags: java, sorting, hashmap

I would like to ask for help. Let's say I have HashMap with key-value like this:

```
String1 0.99
String2 0.98
String3 0.97
String4 0.98
String5 0.5
String6 0.4
String7 0.3
etc.
```

And I would like to save to array the top 15 entries by this formula: `Math.abs(value - 0.5).`

The counted values (by the formula) for this data would be:

```
String1 0.49
String2 0.48
String3 0.47
String4 0.48
String5 0
String6 0.1
String7 0.2
```

The values sorted

```
String1 0.49
String4 0.48
String2 0.48
String3 0.47
String7 0.2
String6 0.1
String5 0
```

And now I would like to have array, where index would be the order and value the original value, like this:

```
array[0] = 0.99
array[1] = 0.98
array[2] = 0.98
array[3] = 0.97
array[4] = 0.3
array[5] = 0.4
array[6] = 0.5
```

Thanks everyone for help

Any help would be appreciated. Thank You

Comment: Your question is unclear. What are the keys? What are the values? What does "the top 15 entries by this key" mean?

Comment: @JBNizet the keys are strings, the values are floats, and "by this key" should read "by this formula."

Comment: OK. Then transform the map into a list of entries, use a custom comparator sorting the entries the way you want, and keep the first 15 elements.

Answer (score 1):

First option is to iterate over the whole map and find your values - perhaps throw it into an array and use an O(n * log n) sort algorithm or 15*O(n) walks over it.

Can you drop the condition that the keys are unique? Then work with ordered pairs (String, float) and write a customer `Comparator` that implements your rule on the "float" value, and use a `SortedSet`.

There may be a solution involving `BiMap`, I'm not sure.

Comment: A SortedMap won't help: the OP wants the top values, not the top keys.

Comment: Please could You provide some example how to iterate over the whole map and find the values? I canť put it together.

Comment: `List<Map.Entry<String, Float>> listOfEntries = new ArrayList<>(map.entrySet());` Now sort this list using a comparator that compares entries based on your rule.

Comment: @PavelStraka did you try googling "how to iterate over the whole map and find the values"? Let me know if your answer doesn't appear there for some reason.

Comment: @djechlin: Of course I know how to iterate throuh HashMap, but I am not sure, how to get 15 values by mentioned formula of Hash Map into array.

Comment: @PavelStraka oh, you should have clarified. did you try googling something like...  idk "iterate and get top values"? does that work?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Java 8 stream API:

```
List<Double> result = map.values().stream()
        .map(value -> Math.abs(value - 0.5))
        .sorted()
        .limit(15)
        .collect(toList());
```

Comment: I get an error: The method toList() is undefined for the type "ClassName". Edit: Should I use Collectors.toList() instead?

Comment: That won't return the top 15 entries. It won't even return the top 15 values. If the OP really means entry, then it's incorrect. But the question is still unclear.

Comment: We don't know what you really want as a result. What does "top" mean? smallest, or largest? What do you want as a result, a list of map entries, a list of keys, a list of values, or a list of absolute values of `v - 0.5`. Give a concrete example, with real keys, real values, and a real desired result.

Comment: @JBNizet: OK, I edited the original question, hope this helps to clarify my question.

Answer (score 0):

OK. So you have a map, but you only care about its values. So let's start by getting the values out of the map:

```
map.values()
```

Then you want to sort these values. So you need a comparator. This comparator should sort by `Math.abs(value - 0.5)`

```
Comparator<Float> comparator = 
    Comparator.comparing((Float value) -> Math.abs(value - 0.5F));
```

But the values leading to the largest difference should come first, rather than last. So let's reverse the comparator:

```
Comparator<Float> comparator = 
    Comparator.comparing((Float value) -> Math.abs(value - 0.5F))
              .reversed();
```

Now you need to apply that comparator, and only take the 15 first values:

```
Comparator<Float> comparator = 
    Comparator.comparing((Float value) -> Math.abs(value - 0.5F))
              .reversed();

List<Float> top15 = map.values()
                       .stream()
                       .sorted(comparator)
                       .limit(15) 
                       .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Or, if you really want an array rather than a List:

```
Float[] top15 = map.values()
                   .stream()
                   .sorted(comparator)
                   .limit(15) 
                   .toArray(Float[]::new);
```

Comment: I get two errors on the row Comparator<Float> comparator = .... 1. Type mismatch: Cannot convert from Comparator<Object> to unknown. 2. The operator - is undefined for the argument type(s) Object, float. Where am I wrong?

Comment: Oh, I missed the explicit Float type in the comparator. Fixed now.